# Can not seem to successfully pass through a variable through to a laravel Route

Tags: laravel

I am a complete newb trying to teach myself the laravel framework.  I have a little PHP experience from a past life and am just trying to learn a new skill set.  I am def not a developer by trade.

I am trying to complete a tutorial on routes.

In my web.php file I have this

```
Route::get('/test/{post}', function($post) {

$posts = [
    'my-first-post' => 'Hello, this is my first blog post!',
    'my-second-post' => 'Now I am getting the hang of this blogging thing',
    'test' => 'test'
];

if (! array_key_exists($post, $posts)) {
    abort(404, 'Sorry, that post was not found');
}

return view('post', [
    'post' => $posts[$post]
]);
});
```

In my blade file I have this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>
        This is a test
    </title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                this is a test
                {{$post}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I refresh the page with the following URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/test

I get the following error

InvalidArgumentException
View [post] not found.

Am i doing something silly?

Answer (score 1):

Through the exception it seems that the view 'post' does not exist.

Please make sure that post.blade.php exists in project_root/resources/views/post.blade.php

For further details please refer to this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#creating-views

Comment: Thank you!  I think i know what i was doing wrong.

I was using a test.blade.php to render the page.

the Route::get(/test/{post} referred to it but not the return view('post')

appreciate the help :)